# Getting value from key pair value into appended property using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the value from a key pair value into the rel property of an anchor tag?

When I split the code to put the value in the correct place it doesn't work, the end of the a tag would appear on screen instead value wouldn't be applied. When I look at the resulting code in console in Firebug the rel and href swapped order so the rel is first.

The 'key' should be and is in the correct location but the 'value' needs to be applied to the rel attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
 var obj = {"firstThing":"4","secondThing":"6","aThirdThing":"2","anotherThing":"3","followedByAnother":"4"};

 $.each(obj, function(key,value) {

  $('#newmine').append("<li class='tagBlocks'>","<a href='#' rel=''>",value," ",key);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it up a bit to use the jQuery functions instead of building the string, like this:

```
$(function() {
 var obj = {"firstThing":"4","secondThing":"6","aThirdThing":"2","anotherThing":"3","followedByAnother":"4"};

 $.each(obj, function(key,value) {  
    $("<li class='tagBlocks'></li>").append(
        $("<a href='#'></a>").attr('rel', value).text(key)
    ).appendTo("#newmine");
 });
});​
```

The swap occurs because well...it's the javascript and that's the DOM.  The order doesn't matter, it's just a list of properties, so whatever the browser processes first may or may not appear first in whatever debugging tool you use.  Whatever the position, the effect is the same, so the order you see in the debugger may be different for every single browser...in this case that's ok :)

Comment: Do you think the jQuery methods are faster than building the string (I don't think so)? Or because of (maybe) better readability?

Comment: @Felix - Depends on how many elements...remember that `$(htmlHere)` creates a document fragment that is cached (up to 512 bytes), and that's not cheap to create, dynamically creating a string prevents that cache from happening because each one is unique.  In this case building `<li class='tagBlocks'><a href='#'></a></li>` as a fragment and doing a find is faster, but yes, I went for readability :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: Ah I didn't know about the caching. Thanks for the insight, I guess I have to investigate on this further :) (taken the loop into account than indeed your approach might be better). +1

Comment: @Felix - Here's the commit that it changed in, search for 512 in it: http://github.com/rkatic/jquery/commit/ac200983bfddd98334dacccd727fd467a06357c7  I can't find good documentation online, but Resig has spoken about it at several talks....if you have time for video, this has a snip in it (I think about halfway through, having trouble scanning, better to download): http://loft.bocoup.com/john-resig-advanced-jquery/ However, he discusses some of the rarely used things overall, I'd watch if all if you get the time to.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Thanks again, seems to be very interesting video. I have to spend some hours in the train today so this is perfect to spend my time :)

Comment: @Nick Craver. Thanks for your help on this and the excellent explanation.

Comment: @Nick Craver. I just went to test the code in Safari and discovered the code doesn't seem to work, just an empty space where the list should be. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Nick Craver. Yeah that works fine in isolation. It looks like it is something else on the page that is conflicting and causing the problem in Safari. I'll have to track it down. jsFiddle is awesome, I hadn't come across that before. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this more closely:

```
"<li class='tagBlocks'>","<a href='#' rel=''>",value," ",key
```

You have put `value` **after** the `>` which closes the `a` tag.
I just would generate one string and append it:

```
'<li class="tagBlocks"><a href="#" rel="' + value + '">' + key + '</a></li>'
```

Comment: great, thanks that works a treat.

Can you tell me why the href and the rel get switched when they appear in console in Firebug?

Comment: @Neil: This is just how Firbug displays attributes (it sorts them somehow I think). In the end it doesn't matter in which order they are, as you always access them via name. Think about the attributes as a hashtable (key -> value ). Hashtables don't have any order.

Comment: +1 For being correct in answer and comments, attributes are literally hashtables in some browsers, and at least behave like them in all :)